# Android DataBinding Dynamic addView

Tags: android

I have two layout xml **A** and **B**

A linearlayout in **A** xml with id 'layout'

Now I want to add **B** in layout using `layout.addView()`

How can i do this by using `databinding`

Answer (score 9):

I don't think this is the best practice, but here's how I dynamically added views with `databinding`.

In layout `A`, I have a `FrameLayout` like below:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    bind:createView="@{viewModel.dynamicViews}">
```

In my `viewModel` class, I have a static method with `BindingAdapter` annotation,

```
@BindingAdapter("bind:createView")
public static void createImproveView(FrameLayout layout, LinearLayout replacement) {
    layout.removeAllViews();
    layout.addView(replacement);
}
```

and I have my replacement layout here:

```
public LinearLayout getDynamicViews() {
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(mContext);
    // dynamically add views here. This could be your layout B.
    return layout;
}
```

I couldn't find any other solutions, and this was working fine for me. Please give me any comments, I'm open to learn better solutions!

Comment: In which class did u add getDynamicViews() method? Curious because it uses context.

Answer (score 3):

`addView(databinding.getRoot())`
you can see the `getRoot()` return a `View` instance, so you can `addView` by this method.

This databinding is the databinding instance of the view you want to add.

Comment: I think this is better than the most upvoted answer because view model should do the data creation, and hold no reference to the context, that means having a view in the view model is no go, so we have to resort back to the old direct methods

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the same using the layout xml . Use the include control like this:

```
<include layout="@layout/header_logo_lyt" //Name of xml you want to include/>
```

Comment: Include is not databinding